# How can I scope a Sunspot query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, scope, sunspot

My trouble with this snippet is that it's returning an integer `-1` which means a universal `Message` that is shared in other accounts as well.

```
  def build_results
    search = Sunspot.new_search(Message) do
      any_of do
        member.lists.map { |list| with :enterprise_list_id, list.search_id }
      end
```

How can I add on to this statement to query all Message's with `-1` as a `search_id` but scope it so that it belongs exclusively to `member.account` ?

I'm trying to scope it as so :

```
searchable :include => :repliable do
  integer :account_id do
    repliable.try(:account_id)
  end
```

and..

```
def build_results
  search = Sunspot.new_search(Message) do

    with :account_id, member.account_id
```

But this returns nothing even though I know for a fact that there are search results that should be returned because they share a commont `account_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then you just need to add this statements in your Message searchable block.

```
searchable do
  integer :some_search_ids, :multiple => true do
     member.lists.map { |list| list.search_id} if member.present?
  end

  integer :member_account_id do
    member.account_id if member.present?
  end
end
```

then,

```
def build_results
  search = Sunspot.new_search(Message) do
    with(:some_search_ids, some_list_search_id)
    with(:member_account_id, some_member_account_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: That was my thoughts exactly. Strangely enough, that makes no results return.

Comment: Do reindex the sunspot-solr every-time you change the searchable block

Comment: I have been. Even going so far as rebooting solr each time as well ( which I imagine is unnecessary ). Is there something I might be missing from your example? Why did you choose `member.lists`map` ? Are you suggesting that my example, `integer :account_id do` should be mapped and return an array always? Further, can `:some_search_id` be a wildcard attribute not present in the schema?

Comment: I just edited my code. Just tell me you need to search messages using list.serach_id no? Here I'm confuse about account_id. In my searchable block I indexed with virtual object i.e. :some_search_ids (You can change it) and I just added :multiple => true so that this filed will be indexed on multiple values (the method/block used to generate the data returns an Array). In that block I'm actually mapping with real object i.e. list.search_id.

Comment: So when sunspot searches using :some_search_ids It will search on search_id of every list which is indexed. In build_results method some_list_search_id should be some list.search_id

Comment: Ah I see what you did. Thank you. But how would you *constrain* the `some_search_ids` within the scope of the `account_id` ? Both my example, and your example will return the same data, which is the searched for `search_ids`, but would I ensure that those only come back from the Member's account, and not someone else's account since several Accounts can have lists with the same `search_id`.

Comment: I just edited the code. If I understood it correctly then this code should work. Please reindex and try with this new code.

Comment: There is actually no difference between your example, and my original example. Unless I'm missing something?